# I want to delete values from table1 and store in table1 by executing Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How and what query should i write to execute trigger before executing a delete statement...

I want to delete values from table1 and before deleting values, i am storing these values in table2 but the problem is that whenever i execute trigger and then statement then both executes but the values from table1 doesn't deleted. Trigger executes correctly (Using SQL Server 2008)

Comment: Please show the way that you defined your trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 'merge' statement in a procedure or trigger that would be easier with SQL Server 2008 and higher.  Merge enables inserts, updates and deletes and gives output all in one statement.

Example use here: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/28/sql-server-2008-introduction-to-merge-statement-one-statement-for-insert-update-delete/